# determine the directory where test cases should be run on it

Tags: java, junit, testcase

My program gets as input a jar file and a directory contains Java source code. The jar file contains test cases that should be run on the input java source codes. If I define java input directory as source folder, then I can load test cases and run them as below:

```
URLClassLoader clsLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] {new URL("file:/D:/workspace/tests.jar")});

    //the name of my test case class that I want to load
    Class cls = clsLoader.loadClass("temp.testMulDiv");

    Result result = new JUnitCore().run(cls);
    for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) 
        System.out.println(failure.toString());
```

However, while I put the source code as an input directory, then test cases can not find the code. I know that I should in someway tell test cases to search for source code in the input directory, but I do not know how to do that. Any suggestion?

I also check this piece of code, but still I have the above problem. While I can load the method that I want to run, but in this case "Class.forName" can not find the class ("temp.testMulDiv") and I get "ClassNotFoundException" error.

```
URLClassLoader clsLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] {new URL("file:/D:/workspace/tests.jar")});

    //the name my test case class that I want to load
    Class cls = clsLoader.loadClass("temp.testMulDiv");

    Method[] methods = cls.getDeclaredMethods();
    // I want to run only the first method
    Request request = Request.method(Class.forName(cls.getName()), methods[0].getName());

    Result result = new JUnitCore().run(request);
        for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) 
            System.out.println(failure.toString());
    }
```

Any suggestion, how can I run test cases on an input directory (and not a source folder)? How programmatically can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

A good practice is to place test classes in the same package as the source Java classes so that they have visibility of each another.

For example, in Maven, you would have `src/main/java`, and `src/test/java` to contain the source Java classes and test classes respectively. These are standard Maven layouts.

Say i have a source Java class `MyService.java` in `net/java/service`:

```
src/main/java/net/java/service/MyService.java
```

Then i should place the corresponding test class `MyServiceTest.java` in `net/java/service` too:

```
src/test/java/net/java/service/MyService.java
```

Assume you have the following public method in MyService.java:

```
public void multiDiv(){
  ...
}
```

Then you should have the following test method in MyServiceTest.java:

```
@Test
public void testMultiDiv(){
  MyService service = new MyService();
  service.multiDiv();
  // assert ....
}
```